# Using the PromtDialog.Text just shows the text and not a textarea?

Tags: .net, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service, csx

Ì'am trying to create a promptDialog were the user inputs some text.

[Documentation for PromptDialog](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/d9/d03/class_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_builder_1_1_dialogs_1_1_prompt_dialog.html#)

Code:

```
  PromptDialog.Text(
            context,
            ResumeAfterAnswerAsync,
            "What is your name?",
            null, 5);
```

When this is triggered it only show up as a basic reply from the bot with the message: "What is your name?" like the image below. What I expected was a textarea in a dialogbox. Kind of like the prompt dialog Confirmation dialog you can see at the bottom of the screenshot, only with a input field.

[image: Screenshot of bot emulator]

Is this behaivor by design? Meaning that the next message sent to server is the input. Or am i doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. Having a text area doesn't make sense as most of the channels won't be able to render it.